# Avoid errors using Interop if the COMponent aren't installed

Tags: c#, com, interop, office-interop, text-to-speech

> "If you want to use Interop, then the component should be installed in
>   the system. Otherwise, it won't work."

I have a WinForm application, that is used by many users in several SO (WinXP, Win7, Win8.1, WinServer 2008, WinServer 2012)

In development, I use a COM component (Outlook, SpeechLib,...).

Two keys:

1. Some users cannot installed the component. Or they haven't installed it.
2. Another users can be installed the component.

Any programatically way to:

- avoid the application fails for the users that hasn't installed the component
- the application works for the users that has installed the component

?

**Notes:**

Programmatically way to determine whether a particular COM library DLL has been installed or is installed. Anyways, if a particular COM library not installed, the target is that my source code not fails in runtime in that machine without that COM installed.

For example, for **Excel, Word, Outlook COM (ActiveX), SpeechLib (Microsoft Speech Object Library)**, etc

I could have source code like this:

```
 SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags SpFlags = SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync;
    SpeechLib.ISpeechVoice speech = new SpeechLib.SpVoiceClass();
    // ....
```

Or anyways using Outlool application class, or Excel.Application, etc.

```
Type officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
if (officeType == null)
{
    // Excel is not installed.
    // Show message or alert that Excel is not installed.
}
else
{
    // Excel is installed.
    // Continue your work.
}
```

My old issue, but not solution:

Detect Outlook installed and load dynamically INterop.Outlook
[Detect Outlook installed and load dynamically INterop.Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421176/detect-outlook-installed-and-load-dynamically-interop-outlook)

> I have a Windows Forms application in VS2010. It has a reference to
>   Interop.Outlook (2003). Then, I have reinstalled Windows XP and
>   VS2010, but not install Outlook.
>
> Now, the project not compiles.
>
> I think this, my application will not work if Outlook not installed in
>   machine that my program executes on.
>
> I need to know if I detect Outlook installed, and load dynamically
>   Interop.Outlook.dll (for using the Outlook PIA or Embedded Interop
>   types in .NET 4).
>
> If the machine has Outlook (2003, 2007, 2010, perhaps need code to
>   detect version and do compatibility of Outlook versions) installed,
>   the application works fine with functionally Outlook.
>
> If the machine hasn’t Outlook installed, (in runtime) the application
>   works fine without functionally Outlook. I think, If the machine
>   hasn’t Outlook installed, (in runtime) the application fails because
>   references (in source code) to Outlook.Application class?.
>
> In development machine, the application works because Outlook (and
>   COM) is installed in the machine.
>
> Any sample source code or goog patterns and practices about it??

**References**

Does this code fails if Office not installed in machine ?
[How to detect installed version of MS-Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266675/how-to-detect-installed-version-of-ms-office)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/679027/How-to-Check-Whether-Excel-is-Installed-in-the-Sys?msg=5027820#xx5027820xx
[How to check, programatically, if MS Excel exists on a pc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123196/how-to-check-programatically-if-ms-excel-exists-on-a-pc)

http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/07/07/faking-com-to-fool-the-c-compiler

Comment: Where is the question? It seems you have already found the solution with the Type.GetTypeFromProgID method.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev   
***"If you want to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, then the component should be installed in the system. Otherwise, it won't work."*** I compile my assembly with this code `olkApp1 = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); olkMail1 = (MailItem)olkApp1.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);` _When assembly is loaded, not fails if COM not installed?_

Answer (score -1):

I posted this elsewhere, but here's the code to detect if Outlook is installed. Basically, it tries to get the Outlook automation object.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var outlookType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application");
        if (outlookType == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not installed.");
        }
        else
        {
            var app = Activator.CreateInstance(outlookType) as Application;
            Console.WriteLine(app.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

For SpeechLib, I think the right way to detect it is to just try and create a "new SpVoice()" instance wrapped with a try/catch. If it fails, then assume speech is not installed. Again, embedding the interop will allow you to avoid runtime type load issues.

Hope that helps.